# One to many table creation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, entity-relationship

I'm really new to Hibernate and this is my first app which is enterprise level.
I'm stuck at one to many mapping. I did the mapping whole day but it doesn't give to correct table structure for me.

Here is the ER diagram I want to map
[image: ER Diagram]

These are the Classes

Feed Class

```
@Entity
public class Feed {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String name;
private long quantity;
//With getters and setters
}
```

Feed Order Details Class

```
@Entity
public class FeedOrderDetail {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private double unitPrice;
private long quantity;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name="feed_id")
private List<Feed> feed = new ArrayList<Feed>();

//Getters and Setters
}
```

after deploying app I get the following table structure

[image: Table Structure]

My problems are 
why feed_id is in Feed table?
Should I add same feed every time I add a feed order detail? (it isn't a good idea)

I can achieve this by moving @OneToMany annotation and attributes to Feed table. but if I move it to Feed class how can I represent feed order details in JSP pages?

I'm using spring with this project also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to have a object reference on both sides of the relationship.

So have a reference to `List<FeedOrderDetail>` in Feed and have a single refernce to a Feed in your `FeedOrderDetail`.

Class Feed:

```
@Entity
public class Feed {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private long quantity;
    //With getters and setters

    // !new!
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "feed") // mappedBy references the fieldname in the other Java class
    private List<FeedOrderDetail> details;
}
```

Class Detail:

```
@Entity
public class FeedOrderDetail {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Long id;
     private double unitPrice;
     private long quantity;

     @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
     @JoinColumn(name="feed_id")
     private Feed feed; // only a single feed reference

     //Getters and Setters
}
```

If you want to get a list of feeds using Hibernate's JPA API, then you can use this code:

```
TypedQuery<Feed> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT f FROM Feed f", Feed.class);
List<Feed> feeds = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Your answer work like a charm. but how can I put these fields in JSP page. because List is in Feed class? How can I access in a jsp form?

Comment: @thusithaniroshan I added some code that shows how to retrieve a list of feeds. Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You designed it backwards. You schema says that 1 Feed instance includes M FeedOrderDetail instances.

So, in the class Feed, you should have a `List<FeedOrderDetail>`. But that's not what you've done. You have a `List<Feed>` in FeedOrderDetail.

Comment: if we move M side to Feed table every time we add a feed order detail we have duplicate rows of feed. isn't it?

Comment: I didn't suggest you to mobe the M side to Feed. I suggested exactly the inverse thing: your schema is correct, but your code is not, because it doesn't respect the schema. A Feed has many details. That's what you want. But what you coded, in Java, is "A detail has many feeds".

Comment: oh ok. my bad.sorry for misunderstanding. I get it now.thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The correct one is:

```
@Entity
public class Feed {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String name;
private long quantity;
//With getters and setters
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE, mappedBy="feed")
private List<FeedOrderDetail> orders = new ArrayList();
}
```

And

```
@Entity
public class FeedOrderDetail {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private double unitPrice;
private long quantity;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name="feed_id")
private Feed feed;

//Getters and Setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My problems are why feed_id is in Feed table?

You are right, it should not be in case your ER diagram is right.

Your ER diagram and table structure does not match, so I am trying to give you class mapping according to your ER-diagram.

**Feed.java**

```
@Entity
public class Feed {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String name;
private long quantity;
//With getters and setters
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "feed")
    public Set<FeedOrderDetail> getFeedOrderDetail() {
        return this.feedOrderDetail ;
    }
}
```

**FeedOrderDetail.java**

```
@Entity
public class FeedOrderDetail {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private double unitPrice;
private long quantity;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FEED_ID", nullable = false)
    public Feed getFeed() {
        return this.feed;
    }

//Getters and Setters
}
```

I hope it helps :)